# At what point is refining more efficient than cutting?

Tags: kittens-game

When kittens-game begins, our only option to obtain wood is by refinement. As the game continues, we have access to woodcutters, and they pretty clearly are more efficient than refining (see this question "[When are Woodcutters more efficient than refining catnip?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184048/when-are-woodcutters-more-efficient-than-refining-catnip)").

Later on however there are many upgrades to refining, with bio labs being one quite late and substantial upgrade (an additional 10% efficiency per lab). I noticed that a farmer's base rate for catnip is 5/sec and a woodcutter's base rate is 0.075/sec. It seems to me that it is already more efficient to refine than to chop.

I'm not always paying 100% attention, so I believe it is still a good idea to have a couple of woodcutters so that production is in the positive. All the rest of my woodcutters should be farmers, right?

I'm new to the late game. In late-game, are woodcutters obsolete? At what point does refining become more efficient than woodcutting?

Comment: The tooltip for refining also appears wrong; it claims that 50 catnip converts to 1 wood, regardless of how many bio labs one has.

Comment: But catnip production is affected by the seasons.... hmmm... I think this one is quite tricky!

Comment: Farms are. Farmers aren't.

Comment: imo woodcutters are by far more efficient then refining. You (at least, I) haven't got the time to think every few minutes of clicking refine all. Maybe it is more efficient for wood, but wood isn't the resource I lack (1 million beams) or I remember to lack at any point in the game, except for the very beginning. It is mostly the manuscript/compendium/blueprint cycle I need. Therefor I leave the game running overnight to gain those resources, and I cannot refine at all. With woodcutters, I have also a lot of wood (no pun intended)

Comment: I wouldn't pay too much attention to the base rate because the different percentages from your aqueducts and farms will change that.  What really matters is how much each kitten contributes to your total production.  That's easy to test - remove a woodcutter and see how much your production drops, do the same for a farmer.  Do the conversion for catnip and compare, higher number wins.